# How to retrieve the image output from tensorflowlite interpreter

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I have retrained pretrained neural network ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8 with tfrecords of custom images.

The colab notebook link is https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zTGsWaeAM3yOdQ5kJ7Z47jNCs-GSo02Q?usp=sharing

The model is performing reasonable inference within colab. Now I create Tensroflow interpreter using model.tflite file.

After calling the interpreter.invoke() call, the ouptut tensor need to have the output image. I am unable to infer it from the output details..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of depending on tensor names, consider using signature concept.

```
# Load the TFLite model in TFLite Interpreter
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(TFLITE_FILE_PATH)

# Print signature information to find out the input/output names.
signature_defs = interpreter.get_signature_list()
print(signature_defs)

# my_signature is callable with input as arguments.
my_signature = interpreter.get_signature_runner()
output = my_signature(image=input_tensor)

# 'output' is dictionary with all outputs from the inference.
print(output)
```

See more the [detail](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python).